# How to ensure an internal interface gets defined

Tags: java, interface

Greetings,

I am trying to set up a pattern where a class definition must include an internal interface definition.  So for instance if someone on my team were to define a class is it possible via an interface or base class to ensure that they have to declare and define an internal interface like below?  I am not concerned with the specific definition of the interface, like what methods they declare, but that an interface named Display was defined at all.

```
public class Foo {

    public interface Display {

        void Bar();
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

I appreciate any insight or pointers to documentation on this subject.

Comment: Why would you ever want to define one internally instead of just implementing one?

Comment: By checking do you mean to check it at run time or did you mean to check it via unit testing (during packaging)?

Comment: Why do you want to force them to define an internal interface?

Answer (score 2):

No way you can do this kind of static check.

Sometimes when you just hear a question you can literally smell bad design. That is exactly that type of question.